# Maximum number of Fourier terms in forecast package

Tags: time-series, forecasting, fourier-transform, multiple-seasonalities

I am using the `forecast` package in R to get some Fourier components - namely, function `fourier(ts, K, ..)`. For a time series `ts`, `K` controls the maximum number of the Fourier terms one gets (sines + cosines of with different frequencies).

However, if the period of the time series is specified as 7, `K` is automatically capped at 3 maximum, or for other periods, $\#\textrm{terms} = \frac{\textrm{Period}}{2}$.

Why is that? I thought Fourier series can be represented by an infinite number of components. Is there some practical issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are observing a discrete series. With a period of $k$ and a constant term already fitted, there are only $k-1$ degrees of freedom for the seasonal terms (there's only $k$ different means you can have in a period with $k$ times, but one is accounted for by the constant). This is the same df you get if you used seasonal dummies.

Because you have both $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms, you normally get two terms each harmonic. So with $k=7$, you get $(k-1)/2=3\,$ $\sin$ terms and $(k-1)/2=3\,$ $\cos$ terms. (With even $k$, you get one term at the end rather than two, because one - the highest order $\sin$ term - doesn't contribute anything.)

Any higher order periodicities would consist of wiggles *between the data points*. You don't observe those.

Comment: Ah, so it is due to the function being discrete? So, as I understood, the first 7 terms approximate all 7 points of the period, while higher order terms try to approximate something which is in-between points, so it makes no sense (since the ts is discrete), and they are simply discarded. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: Essentially, yes; being on a discrete set of points you can only determine as many coefficients as points - and because the points are on a lattice, higher harmonics couldn't do anything anyway.